# i want to convert List<object> to ArrayList but not getting any output

Tags: asp.net

here is my code...

```
[WebMethod]    
    public ArrayList GetDataByModuleName(string ModuleName)
    {
        ArrayList m = (ArrayList)BAL_GeneralService.GetDataByModuleName(ModuleName);
        return m;
    }
```

but not getting any output...

Answer (score 3):

you want to use the constructor:

```
    public ArrayList GetDataByModuleName(string ModuleName)
    {
        ArrayList m = new ArrayList(BAL_GeneralService.GetDataByModuleName(ModuleName));
        return m;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, the `BAL_GeneralService.GetDataByModuleName` does not return any results for the `ModuleName` you passed in.

Comment: it's retuns the List<object> ...as a result

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that BAL_GeneralService.GetDataByModuleName(ModuleName);
 is not returning a null?

Edit:
Since its returning a List you need to pass it to the ArrayList constructor